# элементы массива 2 через 2

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Пропуская 2 элемента сохранить и посчитать сумму следующих 2
Например:

```
int[] array = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
```

0 и 0 пропускаем, 1+0, 0 и 1 пропускаем, 1+0, 0 и 0 пропускаем и так до конца массива, сохранить сумму элементов int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что именно из этого выглядит сложно?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (i / 2 % 2 == 1)
        sum += array[i];
}
```

Или так

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < array.Length - 1; i += 4)
{
    sum += array[i] + array[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: буквально только что написал то что вы обновили))